# jQuery Mobile: should I use pageBeforeShow or pageBeforeChange for last adjustments?

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, show, transition

I'm developing a mobile app in jQueryMobile and PhoneGap. Often, due to the nature of jQM or because it's about loading data, a page will need some last-minute adjustments before it is shown. For example, form fields need to be filled in with dynamically retrieved data, or the contents of list items need to be given a slightly different style in order to fit better.

I am currently doing all these adjustments using the pageBeforeShow event handler. But I wonder if I shouldn't have been using the pageBeforeChange event handler. The jQM docs do not really make it clear how these two events relate to each other, i.e. which is fired first.

**What I know**
I do know the following

- pageBeforeShow and pageShow are triggered after all of jQM's markup (e.g. making list items look pretty) has been applied.
- pageBeforeShow and pageShow are bound to a specific page, whereas pageChange is called whenever a change of page occurs (so if you want to make specifi changes to one page before the user gets there, you need to test the event.toPage property)

**Why I'm asking**
And this is the background why I want to know if page(Before)Change is a better candidate.

jQuery Mobile page transitions are awkward on many devices. The big issue on Android devices is that page changes are jumpy: regardless of the transition type (fade, pop, etc), the page being left by the user will pop back into view briefly after the new page has more or less finished in the browser.
In my experience, this occurs mostly when other animations are running or are started while the page transition takes place. Basically, the Android browser doesn't seem to want to apply transitions to elements that are not actually in view, and it will flip back and forth between jQM pages as a result.
I've already developed a workaround where I delay any markup and form adjustments for a page by about 1000ms, which prevents the flashing but does mean that the user may be seeing these adjustments happen on screen after the page has come into view.

This analysis makes me think that pageBeforeChange might be a better candidate for attaching any markup and form adjustments. But it will be a big rewrite of the code, and I don't know what unforeseen stuff I will be getting into. Anyone have any experience with these events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure `pagebeforechange` would be the best place to do this. I don't see `pagebeforechange` as a page-level event, but more of a site-level event. I use it mainly if I want to take over navigation or to build dynamic pages.

I use `pageinit` when I want to attach event handlers to a page. I use `pagebeforeshow` when I want to change the contents or look of a page before it is shown.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Kiliman. It does confirm that I would need a very good reason to drop pagebeforeshow and switch to pagechange. I'm curious to hear if anyone has tried pagebeforechange and run into trouble. Or had clear sailing :)